# Neural Networks - How are the IRIS input vectors processed?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am just starting to grasp the idea of Backpropagation and MLP Networks. What I have confusion about is that how is the input vectors "clamped" in the input layer ?

For example lets take a mock IRIS dataset-:

```
[5.0,4.4,2.7,1.5,0],
[3.0,3.6,1.8,1.7,1],
[2.0,1.2,3.3.4.2,2]
```

Are these inputs feed in all together in the input layer ? Or are they fed in one by one.

What I mean is that on the first iteration is the first input vector fed like-:

[5.0,4.4,2.7,1.5,1]

and then the error is calculated and then the next input vector is sent ie.

[3.0,3.6,1.8,1.7,2]

OR are they all sent in together as -:

```
[[A vector of all petal lengths],[A vector of all sepal lengths],etc]
```

I know different frameworks handle these differently but feel free to comment on how any popular deeplearning framework would do this. I use DeepLearning4J myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Input vectors are usually fed into neural networks in *batches*. How many vectors those batches contain is dependent on the *batch size*. E.g. a batch size of 128 would mean that you feed 128 input vectors into the network (or less if there aren't that many left) and then update the weights/parameters. The [iris tutorial of Deeplearning4J](http://deeplearning4j.org/iris-flower-dataset-tutorial.html) seems to use a batch size of 150: `int batchSize = 150;` and later `DataSetIterator iter = new IrisDataSetIterator(batchSize, numSamples);`.

Note that there's also a *batch mode* for updating the weights of neural networks, which - confusingly - updates the weights only after *all* input vectors have been fed into the network. The batch mode however is basically never used.

Comment: So each batch contains a group of petal lengths and sepal lengths and so on. So my question is that are those parameters and taken one at a time and fed in into the network on by one OR is it done as a whole, ie. all the petal lengths and sepal lengths in the first batch fed in at one go as a single vector ???

Comment: Each batch contains one or more vectors. Each input vector contains all attributes of exactly one example (e.g. the color and height of one flower). For each input vector there is exactly one corresponding output vector (e.g. contains the species of the flower). So basically with each batch you are feeding a bunch of flowers (input) and their species (output) into the network.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Each time during the training phase, color and height of one flower is inputted and then one output is received. And then the next training example is inputted in the ANN and it carries on until the training set has been exhausted. Then the error of the iteration is calculated and weights adjusted and then the same training set is sent through again with the adjusted weights. AM I RIGHT ?

Comment: Yes, mostly. The inputs within one batch are usually not treated one by one though. Instead, the results are calculated in one or more big matrix operations (i.e. first calculate for all inputs in a batch layer 1 in one matrix operation, then for all layer 2...). That's however a technicality for performance reasons.